# Group consecutive Rows into two rows with start and end

Tags: sql

My Goal is to filter selected data from a huge table.
I work with a huge Table with like millions of rows of data and need to get an efficient way of selecting the data i need.
The table contains values of various measurements including the timestamp and name:

| Name | timestamp | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| temperature | 15:35 | 22 |
| speed | 15:35 | 50 |
| temperature | 15:36 | 22 |
| speed | 15:36 | 50 |
| temperature | 15:37 | 22 |
| speed | 15:37 | 50 |
| speed | 15:38 | 50 |
| temperature | 15:38 | 25 |

I work with statements like this

```
Select * from MeasurementValues where Name like 'speed'
```

This returns me the values that i then put into a Diagram. The problem is it takes way too much time to put all points into that diagram. Because  the Points mostly stay at the same value i want to put a filtering in my Statement.**I want to Group consecutive entries with the same values and only return the first and last entry.**
For example if i want to have the Values for Speed i only want the results:

| Name | timestamp | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| speed | 15:35 | 50 |
| speed | 15:38 | 50 |

For the Values of temperature i want following results:

| Name | timestamp | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| temperature | 15:35 | 22 |
| temperature | 15:37 | 22 |
| temperature | 15:38 | 25 |

I hope u understand my problem and can help me with that. My SQL knowledge is pretty basic.

Kind regards

Comment: why for 'temperatire' you have 3 records?

Comment: The First one ist the First row with a temperature of 22, the Second one is the last row with a value of 22. After that i have a value of 25, so need to get that too

Comment: then what about the third row?

Comment: Sorry i edited that in. The value Changes to 25. Thats why i Put that row Into there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
select mv.*
from (select mv.*,
             lag(value) over (partition by name order by timestamp) as prev_value,
             lead(value) over (partition by name order by timestamp) as next_value
      from MeasurementValues mv
      where name = 'speed'
     ) mv
where (prev_value is null or prev_value <> value) or
      (next_value is null or next_value <> value);
```

Comment: I gotta Test that tomorrow. Lead and lag ist new to me, but it looks like it does exactly what i want

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly fine and was way more efficent than my previous code.